# How to make User Profile Service work on "condition" when reading data from Oracle

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, oracle

I have an Oracle HRMS along with Sharepoint.

I want User Profile Service to sync with Oracle. UPS will have following fields periodically updated from Oracle.

Employee Name
Employee Number
Marital Status

Now the thing is, when a user's marital status changes, then I want UPS to note down the date and time at which that change happened.

For e.g. if UPS syncs at 2013-12-12 08:30 and notices that previously marital status was "single" and now it has been changed to "married" then it should save current date & time.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The UPS won't do this by itself. You will have to write something custom. I can think of two possible solutions off the top of my head. You could either handle the import and update yourself. Using something like PowerShell run on a schedule that performs the import and then updates both a "Marital Status" property and a "Marital Status Change" property. That would be pretty easy.

Or you could go more complicated and write your own BCS Connector to perform the import and apply the date transformation.

Either way, you would have to store the value on the UserProfile and handle it in a custom way. (Unless the date of the change is already in Oracle, in which case you would just import that date field as well.)

M